# Not able to import views.py in django

Tags: python, django

I am not able to import the views.py module in urls.py module.
I have tried multiple ways,

```
from . import views

import views

from rango import views
```

But none of them works , it just raises `import error`.

Directory structure [image]

urls.py file

[image]

error :-

[image]

I am able to import models.py module in urls.py but not able to import views.py in urls.py even though models.py and views.py are in the same location.

Seems magical !!

Comment: Have you tried `import .views`

Comment: Ya ,It raises syntax error

Comment: There is probably an issue somewhere in your views.py file, can you post it? Or try importing it from a python shell

Comment: Can  you copy and paste the complete traceback.  Your images aren't useful.  The django traceback cuts off before the good stuff.  Also show your urls.py and models.py files as code text in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from .models import MyModel
```

I suggest you read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312102)

Answer (score 1):

I usually import explicitly, for example:

```
from rango.views import add_category
```

But you can try

```
from rango import views
```