# Import custom module to Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a django app and cannot import a custom module inside the views.py file.

I'm trying to import class "Integrate" from auth.py inside modules folder from integrations/views.py

I tried placing `__init.py__` inside the app folder and modules folder but still doesn't work.

[image]

views.py:

```
from ..modules.auth import Integrate
```

Powershell:

```
from ..modules.auth import Integrate
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311812/django-cannot-import-modules?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do this a lot in my projects. Creating custom modules and importing them.

Try this:

```
from modules.auth import Integrate
```

Comment: Thanks, there was no errors but PyCharm still doesn't recognize it. [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/eirp0d)

Comment: See @edgar's comment above for this!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
from .models import Integrate
```

It will be work for  use models

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain I had this exact problem.
It helps if you make the directory holding the module a 'Sources Root'
You right click on the directory and down the bottom of the pop-up is 'Mark Directory As' option.
AFAIK this adds that directory to the PythonPath so the module in there will be found.