# Cant import views django

Tags: python, django, web

I Tried importing app views into my url patterns but i get this error, using newest django version and python 3.11 and if it helps im using the anaconda navigator as a venv alternative

```
  File "C:\Users\IK959\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from chatapp.views import chat_view
ImportError: cannot import name 'chat_view' from 'chatapp.views' (C:\Users\IK959\mysite\chatapp\views.py)
```

this is my directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaqRX.png)

and this is my code for my url pattern and my view

urlpattern:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from chatapp.views import chat_view

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('chat/', chat_view, name='chat'),
]
```

chatapp view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def chat_view(request):
    return render(request, 'chatapp/chat.html')
```

Ive tried the index but i do not know how to do it correctly

---

NEW EDITS:

This is my installed apps

```
 Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'channels',
    'chatapp',
]
```

urls.py app level

```
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views
urlpatterns = [path('chat/', views.chat_view, name='chat'), ]
```

urls.py project level

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("chatapp/", include("chatapp.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: If your current directory is the one that contains "urls.py", then all you need is `from views import chat_view`.  Remember, how would Python know about the directory called "chatapp"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django : Cannot import modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311812/django-cannot-import-modules)

Comment: From OP's urlpattern, chatapp is not registered in the project level urls.py. Also he seems to be mixing up the project level urls.py with the apps urls.py

Comment: Moreover, I've glanced at OP's prior questions and there's a history of asking questions, not providing clarity when community members need it and also not accepting answers.

Comment: Im very sorry for the mistake, I am pretty young and trying to get into this world so not used to this community for the future what other context should i provide?

Comment: @Zatigem i looked over the question but i think they were getting a different error from importing into views from my little knowledge i think mine is from importing the view it self

Comment: Show us your `settings.py`, specially the `INSTALLED_APPS` list

Comment: @Zatigem added the files you wanted but i fixed original error i get a new error: AttributeError: module 'chatapp.views' has no attribute 'chat_view'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this

```
from chatapp.views import chat_view
path('chat/', chat_view, name='chat')
```

in the wrong place. To resolve this, move them from your project level `urls.py` and add it to your apps `urls.py`. In your case, it means you should move them from the urls.py file in mysite directory to the urls.py file in chatapp directory.

Also, I suspect you are following Django's polls tutorial. From the directory you showed in the link, your app has nothing to do with polls. So you might want to change this `path("polls/", include("polls.urls"))` to `path("chatapp/", include("chatapp.urls"))` in your project level urls.py.

**EDIT based on additional requests from OP:**

**urls.py (project level)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("chatapp/", include("chatapp.urls")),    
]
```

**urls.py (app level)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'chatapp'
urlpatterns = [
path('chat/', views.chat_view, name='chat'), 
]
```

Comment: I tried to do this so i moved it to the chatapp urls.py but same result so my url pattern is this now from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from chatapp.views import chat_view

urlpatterns = [
    path("chatapp/", include("chatapp.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
and my chat app urls.py is

from django.urls import path
from chatapp.views import chat_view
path('chat/', chat_view, name='chat'),

what else should i try

Comment: when doing this is the new error 
File "C:\Users\IK959\mysite\chatapp\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatapp.views import chat_view
ImportError: cannot import name 'chat_view' from 'chatapp.views' (C:\Users\IK959\mysite\chatapp\views.py)

Comment: In Django, a project is made up of apps. In your case your project is mysite and your app is chatapp. I can assume this based on the directory you shared. Your project (mysite) should have a urls.py file. That is where you should have this `urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]`

Comment: This project level urls.py is created automatically when you create a new Django project. You can just edit it to register your apps.

Comment: Then there is the app level urls.py which you create by yourself. That is where you have codes like this `urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', chat_view, name='chat'),
]`

Comment: You may have to read up these differences or follow a tutorial because in your question, you mixed up the two.

Comment: Also I'm guessing you included chatapp in the list of installed apps in your settings.py. Also, can you replace `from chatapp.views import chat_view` to `from . import views`. This means from the current directory import views.py module. This should hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: Please note that `from . import views` should be in your app level urls.py because that's the same directory that contains the views.py module. This should fix your issue if you don't have any other mistakes. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it still doesnt work this is the error i get now
                                                                                                                                        File "C:\Users\IK959\mysite\chatapp\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    urlpatterns = [path('chat/', views.chat_view, name='chat'), ]
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'chatapp.views' has no attribute 'chat_view'`

Comment: Can you show your urls.py? Both project level and app level... Show the entire content

Comment: This is a new error which signifies you have a mistake somewhere... Notice The original ImportError has been resolved

Comment: I added the urls.py both levels if you could look over it and show me where i went wrong and why? sorry for late reply was on break

Comment: i tried changing the import to: from .views import chat_view but i get the import error

Comment: you are still mixing up both urls.py but I've edited my answer. So look at my answer again from the section **EDIT based on additional requests from OP** and see the correction I made on your project level and app level urls.py.

Comment: You don't need this `from . import views` in your project level urls.py because you're not importing your views to the project, you are importing it to the app so it should be in the app level urls.py instead. Also, you didn't register your app_name in your app level urls.py. This should come before your urlpatterns list `app_name = 'chatapp'`

Comment: Also I removed this from your app level urls.py `from django.shortcuts import render`. That belongs to your views.py and I can already see it there. Hopefully all these corrections should fix your errors.

Comment: i get the same attribute error saying chat_view doesnt exist in chatapp.views

Comment: i made a new enviroment which worked thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding